# Files exported from google drive sometimes don't have a content-length header field

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I have an app that's downloading files from google drive, exported as pdfs, using `GTMHTTPFetcher`.

All files are downloaded correctly but the fetcher's `response.expectedContentLength` property returns -1 for some files. The response is also missing the content-length field for these files.

I tried setting "Accept-Encoding" to "" in the request's header but that doesn't solve the problem.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Is this the link to your mentioned API / code: http://code.google.com/p/gtm-http-fetcher/

Comment: Yes, but I don't think the problem is objective-c specific. I also tried running the requests using a RestClient and it's not returning a content-length field in the response header for some files. I thought the problem was that google drive files are getting gzipped but setting "Accept-Encoding" to blank should avoid that.